# How do I unbake lighting?

Tags: texturing, materials, lighting

I'm still new to Blender and I got a model of an apartment from sketchfab, and when I added it - it has "vray baked textures" and in the Eevee viewport it looks really bright, can I unbake lighting or textures from it, or whatever I need to do so I can set up my own lighting on the scene?